# ValueError: time data '14.03.2022 00:00:00.000 GMT-0400' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z' (match)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to change the date format of my data but it doesn't seem to work.

here is the error that it give me when I try to run my code "ValueError: time data '14.03.2022 00:00:00.000 GMT-0400' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z' (match) "

here my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# import our historical data
data = pd.read_csv('Data/EURUSD.csv')
data.columns = ['Date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
data = data.set_index(data.Date)
data = data['open','high','low','close','volume']
price = data.close.iloc[:100]

# find our relative extrema
max_idx = argrelextrema(price.values, np.greater, order=1)
min_idx = argrelextrema(price.values, np.less, order=1)

print(max_idx)
print(min_idx)
```

EURUSD.CSV

```
Local time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
14.03.2022 00:00:00.000 GMT-0400,1.09049,1.09177,1.09015,1.09175,6011.13
14.03.2022 01:00:00.000 GMT-0400,1.09175,1.09186,1.09089,1.09116,7262.199999999998
14.03.2022 02:00:00.000 GMT-0400,1.09114,1.09231,1.09093,1.09178,5828.28
14.03.2022 03:00:00.000 GMT-0400,1.09177,1.09407,1.09109,1.09320,12058.280000000004
14.03.2022 04:00:00.000 GMT-0400,1.09321,1.09601,1.09303,1.09567,14770.299999999996
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [strtime.org](https://strftime.org/) `%z` is

> UTC offset in the form ±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]] (empty string if the object
> is naive).

So clearly `GMT-0400` is not valid value for that.

As you are already using `pandas` you might simply do not provide format, which will cause `pandas` to detect it automatically, consider following example

```
import pandas as pd
timestring = '14.03.2022 00:00:00.000 GMT-0400'
timestamp = pd.to_datetime(timestring)
print(timestamp)
```

output

```
2022-03-14 00:00:00+04:00
```